Moq setup for generic method with func parameter with generic return type
I have a generic method as shown below,
public interface IMemoryCacheWithPolicy
{
    TItem GetOrCreate<TItem>(object key, Func<TItem> createItem, CacheItemPriority priorityLevel);
}

I am calling the method like,
var materials = _cacheProvider.GetOrCreate("ActiveMaterials",
    () => _materialService.GetMaterials(false), CacheItemPriority.Normal);

To unit test the calling class, How can i setup MOQ of IMemoryCacheWithPolicy, Tried few of the suggestion provided in other threads, But could not get it to work.
Below are few which i tried, but did not succeed,
 _mockCacheProvider.Setup(
     x =>
         x.GetOrCreate("ActiveMaterials", It.IsAny<Func<IEnumerable<MaterialModel>>>(),
             It.IsAny<CacheItemPriority>())).Returns(_allMaterials);

 _mockCacheProvider.Setup(
     foo =>
         foo.GetOrCreate<IEnumerable<MaterialModel>>("ActiveMaterials",
             (Func<It.IsAnyType>)It.IsAny<object>(),
             It.IsAny<CacheItemPriority>())).Returns(_allMaterials);


Well: var mockProvider = new Mock<IMemoryCacheWithPolicy>(); would do it. Or do you need to setup GetOrCreate to behave is some specific way?

I need to setup GetOrCreate method, I shall edit the question to the ones i have tried.

In which way does the first of the alternatives not work?

Why can't you just specify the generic type? Like: .Setup(x => x.GetOrCreate<TYPEHERE>(...)).Returns(_allMaterials)

Got it to work with following setup,
 _mockCacheProvider.Setup(
 cs =>
     cs.GetOrCreate(It.Is<object>(k => k.ToString() == key),
         It.IsAny<Func<IEnumerable<MaterialModel>>>(),
         It.Is<CacheItemPriority>(p => p == CacheItemPriority.Normal))).Returns(
             (object k, Func<IEnumerable<MaterialModel>> createFunc,
                 CacheItemPriority p) => createFunc());

